# What's the origin of the Conservative recititive?

Tags: music, nuschaot, heterodox, conservative-judaism

I've noticed that people who learned to daven in the Conservative movement have a particular recititive which they use for [weekday nusach](https://soundcloud.com/noah-mulgay/conservative-weekday-nusach/s-DDdvf) and another for Shabbat nusach (this is among those who learned from chazzanim who knew the difference). What is the origin of this nusach?

[recordings to be made and linked]

Comment: Edited from Wikipedia: Recitative is a style of delivery (much used in operas, oratorios, and cantatas) in which a singer is allowed to adopt the rhythms of ordinary speech. Recitative does not repeat lines as formally composed songs do. It resembles sung ordinary speech more than a formal musical composition.

Comment: A recording of this could be helpful.

Comment: @Daniel, uploaded

Comment: huh. I grew up in a Conservative shul and I never heard it said that way. When I had my bar mitzvah, I was taught it like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE9_9zekHY0&t=14m55s (which I also hear in Orthodox synagogues)

Comment: Also, what's the _nusach_ for _Shabbat_ that you're asking about?

Comment: @Daniel, I forgot it

Comment: @Daniel, that's what I heard from my uncle (a Conservative rabbi/ interim chazzan at his schul)

Comment: @Daniel. I think when you hear this melody in an orthodox shul, the davener learned it in a Conservative congregation.  (I know personally of a few such cases.)

Comment: "this nusach": you mean both?

Comment: The audio @Daniel links to sounds to my untrained ears the same as the audio the question links to.

Comment: @msh210, the link in the OP is my own recording

Comment: I suspect it varies by location, but here in the small cities of the American midwest, where many of the Conservative synagogues were Orthodox until 1950 or so, you will hear what Noach posted both from older people that were raised Conservative and those that were raised Orthodox used as an "understated" melody (what you call a recitative).  What Daniel posted is more of the conventional Conservative melody.  I have no proof, but I suspect the Conservative recitative is preserving an older tradition that was common in Ashkenazi shuls in the early twentieth century.

Comment: @Avrohom, in Jewish synagogue music, "recitative" means something different.  A synagogue recitative is a free-form solo setting of the text, usually sounding somewhat improvisatory but possibly fully composed, in a manner more imaginative than the plain nusach.  It can repeat words or phrases in moments of heightened emotion.  As an example, Lewandowski's famous setting of the Shabbat kiddush (the one everyone knows in Ashkenazic circles) can be considered a recitative (except for the "ki vanu vacharta" melody).